# I want to ignore games I have installed on Ubuntu on my Windows 10 version of Steam

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, games, steam, windows-10

Is there any way I can do this?

I prefer Ubuntu 14.04 to Windows anything other than XP.

I have a Dual Boot setup with Windows 10 (for Fallout 4 hur) and Ubuntu 14.04 and I would rather use my Ubuntu boot to play games, but most new games aren't compatible immediately with Wine.

Is there any way I can ignore games on Steam that I am able to/have installed on Ubuntu in my Windows Steam GUI? Only reason for the request - Stops me having to check requirements.

I hope this isn't too convoluted. I have posted to the Windows forums to see if I get an answer as well. Thanks for any response.

Regards in advance.

Comment: steam has a form you know [Discussions](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/)

Comment: Why not share the SteamApps directory for your Wine and Windows Steam installations? That's what I do.

Comment: If you want to filter games on your LIBRARY Click on the LIBRARY Button

Answer (score 0):

For what you're asking, there may be no magic option other than the filter library option already suggested, which doesn't take into account games NOT on your library.
What I do is just look for the SteamOS logo under each game and if it doesn't have the logo then it's not available for Ubuntu but only for Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your game Library too, in Large mode:

[image]

Or in the Small mode:

[image: Steam filter games by platform - Small mode]